# function($) - function(JQuery) What's the difference?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between those two and when should I use each one of them?

Sometimes the script won't work unless I replace the $ with jQuery.

Comment: Your question title isn't very clear

Comment: `jQuery` and `$` are just two global variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that's because `$` is a shortcut for `jQuery` and many other frameworks, which means they can overwrite this variable

if you want to use it, a good practice is to do the following:

```
(function($){
    // here you can use $ and be sure it references jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

if you don't include any other frameworks on your website, then it makes no difference whether you use `$` or `jQuery`

```
console.log(jQuery === $) // true
```